# Reset onclick so value isn't used by ajax script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a beginform that automatically sends EVERYTHING to the controller via a ajax script. The problem is I have one button in the form that should only send its value once per click. I cant seem to distinguish it between the rest of the automatic data.

**GOAL: Once the button is clicked once, i want value 10 (from button) to stop posting to the controller.**

AJAX FUNCTION (SUBMITS ALL DATA TO CONTROLLER)

```
 function toconroller() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.action,
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#box').html(result.info);
            }
        });
    }
```

BUTTON FUNCTION

```
 Function submitonce() { 
//I want to only submit value of button once.
 }
```

BEGINFORM WITH BUTTON

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    { 
    <input id="data" onkeyup="tocontroller();">
   <input type="submit"  name="clicked" id="clicked" value="10" onclick="submitonce();" />
    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. What are you asking?

Comment: I have a button that starts another process in the controller. Since the page auto populates, value 10 (from the button) never goes away once the button is clicked. Once the button is clicked once, i want value 10 to stop posting to the controller.

Comment: only elements with a name attribute will be included when you serialize, so you could just remove the name attribute from the button when you want it to no longer be included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `value` attribute of the submit button when clicked:

```
function submitonce() { 
    $('#clicked').removeAttr('value');
}
```

or do it unobtrusively without using the `onclick` attribute but subscribing to the `.click()` handler using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#clicked').click(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('value');
    });
});
```

or instead of removing the `value` attribute of the button you might want to set it to empty or something else:

```
$('#clicked').val('');
```

And since this is a submit button you might want to cancel its default action of submitting the form by returning false from its click handler (my second unobtrusive jQuery example).